# Move focus to next window on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, window-focus

On OS X you can move focus (also called cycle through windows) to the next window for the same application.

If I have 5 windows open in Finder, I can cycle through them with CMD+shortcut. Only the windows that belongs to Finder will be cycled through.

If I have 5 windows open in Explorer, I have to alt+tab and go through ALL windows for ALL applications.

Isn't possible to cycle through windows like you do on OS X for Windows 7 for one application at a time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the application in question is pinned to one of the first 10 buttons on the taskbar, you can cycle through the windows pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> - <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> repeatedly.

Otherwise, you can use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) to focus the application group and then select the specific window using the arrow keys.